# webpack / laravel mix Error: Chunk.entrypoints: Use Chunks.groupsIterable

Tags: node.js, webpack, laravel-mix

I'm encoutering an error when trying to run 'npm run watch', a command to run the laravel mix watcher.

**In Short**
 1. It works on my Macbook, same OS version, same NPM version, same project.
 2. I tried reïnstalling nodeJS and removed my node_modules.
 3. I tried all kinds of solutions on stack overflow based on the first 
    line on the error log (error: Chunk.entrypoints (...)).

Here is the error log:

```
Johrs-iMac:tdc-roots johrclaessens$ npm run watch

    > pagekit@1.0.0 watch /Users/johrclaessens/stack/TDC/Web/projects/tdc-roots
    > NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

     10% building modules 1/1 modules 0 active                                         
    webpack is watching the files…
                                                                                    77% module and chunk tree optimization unnamed compat plugin/Users/johrclaessens/stack/TDC/Web/projects/tdc-roots/node_modules/webpack/lib/Chunk.js:460
                    throw new Error(
                    ^

    Error: Chunk.entrypoints: Use Chunks.groupsIterable and filter by instanceof Entrypoint instead
        at Chunk.get (/Users/johrclaessens/stack/TDC/Web/projects/tdc-roots/node_modules/webpack/lib/Chunk.js:460:9)
        at /Users/johrclaessens/stack/TDC/Web/projects/tdc-roots/node_modules/laravel-mix/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:176:48
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at /Users/johrclaessens/stack/TDC/Web/projects/tdc-roots/node_modules/laravel-mix/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:171:18
        at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/johrclaessens/stack/TDC/Web/projects/tdc-roots/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:12:1)
        at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/Users/johrclaessens/stack/TDC/Web/projects/tdc-roots/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
        at Compilation.seal (/Users/johrclaessens/stack/TDC/Web/projects/tdc-roots/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:881:27)
        at hooks.make.callAsync.err (/Users/johrclaessens/stack/TDC/Web/projects/tdc-roots/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:464:17)
        at _err0 (eval at create (/Users/johrclaessens/stack/TDC/Web/projects/tdc-roots/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:11:1)
        at _addModuleChain (/Users/johrclaessens/stack/TDC/Web/projects/tdc-roots/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:749:12)
        at processModuleDependencies.err (/Users/johrclaessens/stack/TDC/Web/projects/tdc-roots/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:688:9)
        at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! pagekit@1.0.0 watch: `NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Failed at the pagekit@1.0.0 watch script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /Users/johrclaessens/.npm/_logs/2018-10-24T20_33_19_843Z-debug.log
```

And npm's error log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'run', 'watch' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v8.12.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prewatch', 'watch', 'postwatch' ]
5 info lifecycle pagekit@1.0.0~prewatch: pagekit@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle pagekit@1.0.0~watch: pagekit@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle pagekit@1.0.0~watch: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle pagekit@1.0.0~watch: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/johrclaessens/stack/TDC/Web/projects/tdc-roots/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/johrclaessens/.nexustools:/Applications/DevDesktop/tools
9 verbose lifecycle pagekit@1.0.0~watch: CWD: /Users/johrclaessens/stack/TDC/Web/projects/tdc-roots
10 silly lifecycle pagekit@1.0.0~watch: Args: [ '-c',
10 silly lifecycle   'NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js' ]
11 silly lifecycle pagekit@1.0.0~watch: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle pagekit@1.0.0~watch: Failed to exec watch script
13 verbose stack Error: pagekit@1.0.0 watch: `NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:915:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
14 verbose pkgid pagekit@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd /Users/johrclaessens/stack/TDC/Web/projects/tdc-roots
16 verbose Darwin 18.0.0
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "watch"
18 verbose node v8.12.0
19 verbose npm  v6.4.1
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error pagekit@1.0.0 watch: `NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the pagekit@1.0.0 watch script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Can anyone help me with a fix?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by deleting the project directory and a git clone from the source. a quick npm install and laravel mix ran without any problems.